# Alignment being throw off after successive appends to textarea?

Tags: java, text, textbox, formatting, string-formatting

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgyxd.png

Here's my code for formatting:

```
items.append(String.format("%-30d%-30.2f%-30.2f%-30.2f\n", c, a, s, t));
```

Because each successive number is larger than the next, the alignment is thrown off. How can I preserve the alignment even if the previous number is larger?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the spaces to adjust dynamically to the length of your numeric values, you would need to build your format string dynamically.

### Setup

#### The Item-Datastructure

Let us assume you have the following class `Item` from which you want to display a list:

```
public class Item {

    int number;
    BigDecimal price;
    BigDecimal subTotal;
    BigDecimal total;

    Item(int number, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal subTotal, BigDecimal total) {
        this.number = number;
        this.price = price;
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

#### Setup-method for testing

Let the method `setupExample` provide us with a list of items.

```
static List<Item> setupExample() {
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(10, i));
        BigDecimal subTotal = price.add(new BigDecimal(0.55));
        BigDecimal total = subTotal.add(new BigDecimal(50));
        itemList.add(new Item(i, price, subTotal, total));
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

### Solution

Compute the **format-string dynamically**, given a list of `Item`s.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> itemList = setupExample();
    String formatString = computeFormatString(itemList);
    StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
    itemList.forEach(item ->
                    items.append(String.format(formatString, item.number, item.price, item.subTotal, item.total))
    );
    System.out.println(items);
}
```

The values that we need to compute dynamically are the minimal spacings required for alignment. Each column needs to be **at least as wide as the longest string** representation. For example, if you have two items, (##, ##.##, ###.##, ###.##) and (#, ###.##, ###.##, ###.##), the first column needs to have at least width 2 (the maximum of ## and #) and the second column needs to have at least width 6. The method that computes this format-string could look like this:

```
static String computeFormatString(List<Item> itemList){
    final int PADDING = 1;
    int longestNumber = itemList.stream().map(a -> length(a.number)).reduce(1, Math::max) + PADDING;
    int longestPrice = itemList.stream().map(a -> length(a.price)).reduce(1, Math::max) + PADDING;
    int longestSubTotal = itemList.stream().map(a -> length(a.subTotal)).reduce(1, Math::max) + PADDING;
    int longestTotal = itemList.stream().map(a -> length(a.total)).reduce(1, Math::max) + PADDING;
    return "%-" + longestNumber + "d%-" + longestPrice + ".2f%-" + longestSubTotal + ".2f%-" + longestTotal + ".2f\n";
}

static int length(int integer) {
    if (integer < 10) return 1;
    else return length(integer / 10) + 1;
}

static int length(BigDecimal decimal) {
    return String.format("%.2f", decimal).length();
}
```

We also add a padding, because we want the columns to be separated by at least one whitespace.

**Note** that, if you want to display the **column-headers** too, you also need to take their lengths into account. That is, if the length of a column header is longer than the longest entry, the computed width should be the length of the column header.